# access to an array of pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference, pointer-to-pointer

Why can I access an array of pointers with two parameters, when it's defined as one-dimensional?

I know, I have to work with an array of pointers to access a multi-dimensional array in a function, but I don't know why I can access the array of pointers with two parameters.

```
int a[m][l] { 1,2,3,4, 2,3,4,5, 3,4,5,6  }; //some matrices
int c[m][l];    
int *ap[m];  //array of pointers one-dimensional
int i,j;


for (i = 0; i < m; i++)  //passing the address of first element in each 
        ap[i] = a[i];    //colon of matrix to array of pointers

for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        bp[i] = b[i];

dosomethingwithmatrix(ap[0], bp[0], m, l);



int* dosomethingwithmatrix(const int*ap[], int* bp[])
{
            cp[i][j] = ap[i][j] //accss the array of pointers with two parameters

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `ap[i][j]` is allowed because, it is meaning ful.

Let's check the data types.

- For `int *ap[m];`, `ap` is an array of `int *`s. In case of the function parameter `int*ap[]`, `ap` is a pointer to a pointer-to-int.
- Then, `ap[k]` (referring to the previous point) is an `int *`. This may very well be allocated memory which can provide valid access to more that one `int`s.
- Provided enough memory allocated, `ap[k][s]` will refer to an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Also in C an array is said to *decay* into a pointer.

From the standard (C99 6.3.2.1/3 - Other operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

So:

```
array[i] "decays" to pointer[i]
where pointer has the address of the [0]th element of array
```

And since we have already seen that:

```
p[i] == *(p + i)
```

all we are doing is adding offsets to pointers.

BTW, since addition is commutative, `*(p + i) == *(i + p)`, it gives the sometimes surprising result that:

```
3["hello world"]
```

is a perfectly valid C expression (and it equals `"hello world"[3]`).

Answer (score 1):

Because you can dereference the pointer with index notation. First you access the element (*the pointer*) with an index, now the pointer can be dereferenced too with an index.

The equivalency between that and the indirection operator is as follows

```
pointer[i] == *(pointer + i);
```

Comment: So the second index access the element the pointer is pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

Both of the parameters `ap` and `bp` of function `dosomethingwithmatrix` are *pointer to pointer to int*. They are not array of pointers. The function declarator

```
int* dosomethingwithmatrix(const int *ap[], int *bp[])
```

is equivalent to

```
int* dosomethingwithmatrix(const int **ap, int **bp)
```